# Component is broken only in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I've created a component that repeats inline-block elements with an image a header and some text.

It looks fine in all other major browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Opera).

There was a discrepancy with the width and height but I set it in my CSS and that still didn't fix the problem, I'm using a normalizer to reset browsers to a equal starting point.

Here is my Markup

```
     <!-- Surface Header & Close Icon-->
   <div v-if="products.length == 4" class="products four">
     <div class="header">
       <h3>{{{ surface.label }}}</h3>
       <img @click="surface = {}" src="assets/surface_menu_close_icon.png" alt="Close Icon">
     </div>

     <!-- Products Associated with Surface Click-->
     <div v-for="product in products" class="box" @click="selectProduct(product)">
       <div v-show="product.type == 'Deep'" class="deep-clean"></div>
       <div v-show="product.type == 'Quick'" class="quick-clean"></div>
       <img v-bind:src="product.url" alt="{{ product.name }}">
       <h2>{{{product.name}}}</h2>
       <p>Details ></p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

and here is the CSS associated with that markup.

```
.products {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 5px;
      font-size: 0;

      .box {
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        font-size: 16px;


        .deep-clean {
          height: 12px;
          width: 14px;
          background: url("deep_clean_triangle.png") no-repeat center;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative;
          left: 130px;
          top: -12px;
        }

        .quick-clean {
          height: 12px;
          width: 14px;
          background: url("quick_clean_triangle.png") no-repeat center;
          background-size: contain;
          position: relative;
          left: 130px;
          top: -12px;
        }

        h2 {
          margin: 0 0 10px 0;
          font-size: .9em;
          font-weight: normal;
        }

        p {
          margin: 0;
          font-size: .75em;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: $surface-blue;
        }

        img {
          float: right;
          width: auto;
          height: 90px;
        }

       &.four {
        height: 323px;
        width: 317px;

        }
      }
```

and here is what it looks like on Chrome and the other browsers.
[image: Working(Chrome, Firefox, Opera)]

and here is what it looks like broken on Safari

[image: Broken(Safari)]

Answer (score 1):

By adding

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the box class It fixed all of the problems I was having with safari without affecting the other browsers, the css class now looks like so:

```
.box {
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt it be simpler just to use a html table layout? Then just adjust the style as needed, instead of giving them all exact positions?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Or maybe this helps?

[Relative positioning in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291189/relative-positioning-in-safari)