# Top:50% css not working in safari but it is working in chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center align the text(h1) in a div in angular. The text is aligned properly in Chrome but not working properly in Safari. I am assuming top:50% is not working in safari.
Thanks in advance.

Current CSS:

```
h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

refer image for your reference:

Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Comment: Try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291189/relative-positioning-in-safari

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try `align-self: center` instead

```css
h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-align-self: center; //safari 7+
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but not working. Still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this `-webkit-align-self: center;`

```
h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;/*remove this*/
  transform: translateY(-50%);/*remove this */
  -webkit-align-self: center; //safari 7+
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but not working. Still the same result

Comment: Is safari up to date?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use position properties to do what you need.
If you use [flexbox properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you can do exactly the same thing but probably without the safari weird behavior.

***I don't recommend the usage of CSS hacks using browser extensions like the other answers suggested***

Take a look at my example

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>some text</h1>
</div>
```

*PS: The border and the height properties are there only for visualization purposes, you don't need to use them*

Comment: Thanks for the info! But its not exactly vertically center.